# Syslog-ng 3.0 %95CPU usage?

Tags: syslog-ng

I am using syslog-ng 3.0 in my machines. There is one machine, which gets logs from other three machines. But lately, when I use top to monitor cpu usage (in the main one), I see syslog-ng uses appr.95% of the cpu. I use 2nd depth inclusion in my confs. What could be possible cause for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question -- you need to focus on *system performance*, not a number on a screen.
If your system is operating normally, performance meets your requirements, and your load average is not excessively high (indicating a long wait for process to get the CPU when they ask for it), you have no problem to solve.

If you *are* experiencing a performance problem that's what you should be asking us about (the fact that your CPU is pegged is incidental, and would be helpful when trying to help you solve a performance problem).

---

You don't tell us which "CPU Utilization" number you're talking about, but it really doesn't matter -- It is a common misconception that "100% CPU utilization" is a Bad thing.  **It isn't.**
A computer running at 100% CPU utilization, absent any performance issues, is ***NOT*** a problem, unless you anticipate substantial growth that would over-tax the available CPU bandwidth in the future (within the lifetime of the system).

Comment: Ok, it is true that I don't face with even minor performance issues, but the question is that when I even take two slaves out, the percentage do not change. Isn't it a abnormality??

Comment: @mtndesign that depends on *which* CPU number you're reporting (there are about twelve of them in `top`'s output). Generally however CPU utilization on Unix systems is a number that can (and I would argue *should*) be ignored. Load average (RunQ depth) is a far more meaningful measure of the system's workload.

Answer (score 3):

Syslog-ng does use a lot of CPU resources, yet showing a consistent 95% with a single CPU seems high.  I have a single CPU system w/ <1Gb memory running syslog-ng 2.1.4 for three firewalls (on debug) and 20+ Linux servers (on warn).  Top shows the %CPU as 93-83%.

The filters are very flexible yet do not have any optimization or logic checking; syslog-ng relies on you for that.  Having run into a similar situation, I reviewed all my filters for logic errors and optimized the orders.  Cleanup and optimization reduced my utilization over 10%.  I suggest:

- **Only transmit events worth logging.**  Set the client's priority level to warning or higher.  If you need info priority events from a specific daemon, like authpriv for example, add a /etc/syslog.conf line for that demon.  Fewer events transmitted means less CPU utilization.
- **Place the most frequently hit filters first**, esp. if they eliminate/reduce the logged events. Again fewer events processed means less CPU utilization.
- **Run filters in series** on the logging directive instead of as AND conditions in a single filter.  Includes may be parallel checking both conditions despite one failing.

While you are looking at it, check for disk I/O wait and verify you are using the native UDP protocol (avoid TCP).  Hope that helps.